# Why I am getting error as "ImportError: No module named pyPdf" even after installing PyPdf3

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, pypdf

I am trying to customize a module in Odoo 10. And I have created a addon path for the new module but I have no good right!

I am getting error "ImportError: No module named pyPdf". Since I am beginner on coding industry I find difficult to sort out this issue.  Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: And also I am getting the below error if I install any pyPDF / pyPdf2 / pyPdf3



The directory '/home/sathish/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sathish/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Answer (score 2):

Python3 support was introduced in Odoo 11, IIRC. So just try to install pyPdf for Python2.

Comment: I have tried using  pyPdf and Python2 also. Even that is not working in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a path problem. You should check that the directory containing pyPDF is on the Python path.

```
> # Print a list with the directories in the Python path
> import sys
> sys.path
```

Note: If you are running Odoo under a python virtual environment activate it first.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! But still I need more help as I am getting error "import-im6.q16: not authorized `sys' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037." after using the command mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run using python2

Try this on the terminal,

```
python2 path_to_odoo_folder/./odoo-bin
```

Comment: I tried the above one with an error "python2 path_to_odoo/odoo11/./odoo-bin
python2: can't open file 'path_to_odoo/odoo11/./odoo-bin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"   I have created odoo under this path odoo/odoo11

Comment: replace `path_to_odoo` with you actual odoo path